# Why isn't my for-loop giving me an output on netbeans GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, for-loop, netbeans

I'm working on this assignment where I am to create a GUI on netbeans that asks the user of a starting number and an ending number. The GUI is then supposed to create a for-loop of the numbers between the two numbers entered by the user (including the numbers provided).

I've tried all possible methods, I'm starting to feel that it's a syntax error, but I'm not sure how to fix it. The code I've provided below includes "**" around the terms that are being underlined in my code. Each of these terms are being underlined in yellow, except "printout" which is being underlined in red. Please help me. The final due date is tonight, and I'm still unable to run it through successfully:((

```
   String printOut=this.txtOutput.getText();
        String output= this.txtOutput.getText();
        int a = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText().toString());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText().toString());
        for(int x=a; x<=b; x++){
            printOut = printOut + " " + Integer.toString(x);
        }
        this.txtOutput.setText(printOut);
```

ie; if the user enters 3 as their starting number and 8 as their ending number, the GUI should output: 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.

Instead when I click the enter button, nothing is showing up at all.

Comment: What is the error text from the compiler you're seeing on the `printOut` variable?  For that matter, how are you **not** getting an error on `this.txtOutput.setText(printOut);`?  There is no `setText(String)` method on `String`.

Comment: It's saying that the variable might not have been Initialized and "flip operands of the binary operator". this.txtOutput.setText(printOut); is not being underlined at all which is also what's throwing me off...

Comment: Local variables aren't initialized by default.  When you declare `printOut`, you need to give it an initial value.

Comment: Wait I tried this edited code and I finally got the output I wanted!!! I've edited the code in my question. Sorry about that I'm really new to programming and I just started last week...but thank you so much for the help!:))

Answer (score 1):

You only need set text **ONCE**. Change

```java
for(int x=a; x<=b; x++){
    printOut = printOut + " " + Integer.toString(x);
    this.txtOutput.setText(printOut);
}
```

to

```java
StringBuilder output = new StringBulder();
for(int x=a; x<=b; x++){
    output.append(" ").append(Integer.toString(x));       
}
this.txtOutput.setText(output.toString());
```

Comment: This won't address the issues of not initializing `printOut`, or trying to call methods on `txtOutput` that don't exist.

Comment: I expect that if you post code in your answer, that, at the very least, it will compile.  Yours does not, and even if it did, wouldn't solve the underlying issue.  Setting the text extra times is not the cause of the text never displaying at all.